# pivot headers into rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file  with 2 rows as headers that looks like this:

```
          Day1          Day2        
             X    Y   Z    X   Y   Z
product1   10   12   5   18  22   6
product2    9  100  88  123   4  56
```

If I read this file with pandas, what can I do to make it appear like this?

[image]

Comment: can you provide the chuck of data not as image? It'll be easier to work with

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it:

```
df = pd.read_excel('data_to_pivot.xlsx', index_col=0, header=[0,1])
print(df)
```

```
          Day1          Day2        
             X    Y   Z    X   Y   Z
product1   10   12   5   18  22   6
product2    9  100  88  123   4  56
```

```
df = df.unstack().reset_index()
df = df.rename(columns={'level_0': 'Day'})
df.Day = df.Day.str.replace('Day', '')

df = df.pivot_table(0, ['level_2', 'Day'], 'level_1')
df = df.reset_index(level=1)
df.index.name = None
df.columns.name = None
print(df)
```

```
          Day    X    Y   Z
product1   1   10   12   5
product1   2   18   22   6
product2   1    9  100  88
product2   2  123    4  56
```